# How to pass a value from API to another API using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I have two API, Api A, and API B

I want to read the imageID value from Api A and put the value in Api B under “identifiers”.  There are multiple imageID's in Api-A that I need to loop through and generate a json.  How can I replace  **identifiers** value every time a new imageID is present in Api-A?

API A

```
client_secret = ""

request = requests.Requestor()


path = "path to api”

 params = {
        "businessIdType": "ex",
        "businessId": "example",
        "limit": 50,
        Category": "abc"
    }



    params_str = "&".join([f"{k}={v}" for k, v in params.items()])
    url = "?".join([path, params_str])

    vulns = request.post(
        url=url,
        version=1,
        json = params
    )
    response_data = vulns.json()

    return response_data

         …
```

API A Json  Output

```
"limit": 40,
"vulnerabilities": [
   {
      "labels": [
         {
            "labelKey": "abc",
            "labelValue": "def"
         }
      ],
      "imageId": "abcdefghi",
      "contId": "defghi"
      ...
```

API B

```
client_id = ""
client_secret = ""

request = requests.Requestor()


path = "path to api”

params = {
    "identifierType": "ImageId",

    "identifiers": ['abcdefghi']. ## <--- HOW DO I INSERT THE IMAGEID VALUE HERE FROM THE OUPUT FROM API A
}

    params_str = "&".join([f"{k}={v}" for k, v in params.items()])
    url = "?".join([path, params_str])
    # print(url)

    vulns_y = request.post(
        url=url,
        version=1,
        json = params
    )
    response_data_y = vulns_y.json()

    return response_data_y
```

Comment: @Yalhash I am receiving an error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
`.  how can i fix that?

Comment: The "API A Json Output` isn't valid JSON. Did you forget a `{` at the beginning?

Comment: Please stop asking tell the same questions repetitively and instead edit your original question to provide clarity in response to comments. Duplicate of your previous post [How do i pass the value from json to the second API as the input and loop through it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75750084/how-do-i-pass-the-value-from-json-to-the-second-api-as-the-input-and-loop-throug)

Answer (score -1):

It's a little difficult to understand what's going on in your code with the return value in the first code block, but as long as you have the `response_data` from API A, you can get its imageID like so:

`response_data['vulnerabilities']['imageId']`

So in API B, replace
`"identifiers": ['abcdefghi']`
with:
`"identifiers": [response_data['vulnerabilities']['imageId']]`

See the following link for more info on how to work with the requests library
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/

Comment: I am receiving an error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable . how can i fix that?